# Connected to wireless network, but can't access any web pages

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I'm having problems with my wireless connection; I'm able to connect to the router fine (and I get full signal strength), but whenever I try to connect to a web page (or the router configuration page) it times out. It is the same in all browsers (Chrome, Firefox and IE) and results are the same even entering in the IP address manually.

I am using a [Surf USB Wireless Micro Adapter](http://www.belkin.com/IWCatProductPage.process?Product_Id=525497) which I tried in my Windows 8 laptop (from the same location as my PC) where it worked fine. Furthermore, I can access the internet fine on my PC using an ethernet connection.

The output of `ipconfig /all` for the wireless connection is:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 8:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Surf Wireless Micro USB Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 94-44-52-E6-55-23
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::35a8:5368:b61:b2cb%36(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.84(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 13 December 2013 11:45:33
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 14 December 2013 11:45:42
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 798245970
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-18-37-CD-BE-F4-6D-04-21-B5-70     
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

As mentioned before using an ethernet connection on the same computer works fine, the output of `ipconfig /all` for that is as follows:

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82579V Gigabit Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : F4-6D-04-21-B5-70
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes  
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::6caf:9460:de88:8440%10(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.88(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 13 December 2013 11:48:23
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 14 December 2013 11:48:22
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

I've used tracert to check the connection between my PC and Google's DNS (8.8.4.4) and got the following:

```
Tracing route to google-public-dns-b.google.com [8.8.4.4]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     *        3 ms     3 ms  BThomehub.home [192.168.1.254]
  2    21 ms    19 ms    20 ms  172.16.14.133
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4    37 ms    45 ms    43 ms  217.41.216.29
  5   567 ms    87 ms    29 ms  213.120.176.42
  6    42 ms    30 ms    25 ms  217.41.168.233
  7    23 ms    27 ms    24 ms  217.41.168.109
  8    25 ms    23 ms    27 ms  109.159.249.242
  9     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 10     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 11     *        *     1759 ms  195.99.126.113
 12     *        *     2737 ms  209.85.252.186
 13    25 ms    28 ms    26 ms  209.85.245.2
 14  2508 ms    35 ms    35 ms  66.249.95.173
 15  3657 ms  1518 ms    32 ms  72.14.238.217
 16     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 17  2321 ms    41 ms    37 ms  google-public-dns-b.google.com [8.8.4.4]

Trace complete.
```

So far I've tried

- Resetting the TCP/IP stack
- Reinstalling drivers
- Using different USB ports
- Disabling the firewall

All to no avail. I'm all out of ideas, so any help is very much appreciated.

My thoughts on the issue is that I'm connected to the internet okay, but for some reason the connection is really slow (causing the timeouts). This shouldn't be the case, as I've mentioned other devices connect to the internet fine, and my dongle works fine in my laptop. I have noticed that I am occasionally able to send and receive Facebook messages (using chat) on my PC using WiFi, but actually loading a web page takes too long and times out.

Comment: do u use any proxy programs? such as freegate psyphone or others? may bee your internet explorer had bad proxy configuration

Comment: check that first!

Comment: try in cmd -> ping google.com

Comment: I guess you have a nameserver problem. Try to ping 213.148.130.10. If this does work you could altough use it as a nameserver.
Some networks don't provide a nameserver. But you should probably search the ip address of the nameserver of your provider. If i'm a bad guy this server could send you to any phising site and you wouldn't recognize.

Comment: @Christopher Not using any proxy programs and nothing set up in proxy configuration for any browser (set to default which works on ethernet).

Comment: @Darokthar Request times out, don't think it's a DNS issue as everything works fine on ethernet and configuration is the same on both connections.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

Open cmd as administrator and enter this commands:

```
ipconfig
netsh int ipv4 reset
shutdown -r
```

Then try cmd -> ping google.com

Comment: Already tried resetting TCP/IP (and restarting), but still get the same issue.