# Windows 7: network is up, but can't use any Internet-related program

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

I am having a similar problem to this one:

[Connected to wireless network, but can't access any web pages](https://superuser.com/questions/687898/connected-to-wireless-network-but-cant-access-any-web-pages)

Basically, I have a Windows 7 laptop connected through Wifi to a DSL router. It used to be working perfectly, and then, today, suddenly it didn't. The odd thing is:

- The computer connects to the Wifi access point. Signal strength is excellent.
- `ipconfig` shows that I get assigned an IP address (192.168.0.128), with the default router as 192.168.0.1 and the netmask as 255.255.255.0. Basically, everything looks fine.
- If I open command prompt, and try to `ping www.google.com` or `tracert www.google.com`, it will access the remote host without problems.
- If I do a `nslookup www.google.com`, it returns the correct address too.
- If I do a `telnet www.google.com 80`, it will also connect, and I can issue raw HTTP commands and the remote web server will return HTML pages.

...But the moment I try to open a GUI internet program (Chrome, IE, Skype, anything), it will tell me that I can't connect to the Internet. It doesn't take long either (it's not a timeout): I click "Reload" in Chrome, and it will instantly show me the message "This page cannot be accessed".

Thing I have tried:

- `ipconfig /flushdns` and then `ipconfig /registerdns`.
- Disabled Windows Firewall.
- Resetting the TCP/IP config with `netsh int ipv4 reset` and then rebooting.

Nothing works. What's going on?

Comment: Check you don't have a [proxy](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-internet-explorer-proxy-server-settings#1TC=windows-7) configured.

Comment: +1. Sometimes malware will change your proxy settings. Can you try booting into safe mode?

Comment: To expand on the possible proxy explaination, check your proxy settings: netsh winhttp show proxy

Comment: Please download [MiniToolBox](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/minitoolbox/dl/65/), save it to your desktop and run it.
Checkmark the following checkboxes:  - 
`Flush DNS `
`Report IE Proxy Settings `
`Reset IE Proxy Settings `
`Report FF Proxy Settings `
`Reset FF Proxy Settings `
`List content of Hosts `
`List IP configuration `
`List Winsock Entries  `
`List last 10 Event Viewer log `
`List Installed Programs `
Click **Go** and post the result (**MTB.txt**) in the question (edit it). A copy of Result.txt will be saved in the same directory the tool is run.

Comment: @bjanssen: I thought about the proxy, but didn't know how to check, so thanks for that command. I'll check the next time I have that computer with me (it doesn't belong to me, but to an acquaintance) and will try all suggestions here.

Comment: To answer to everybody who responded: I checked for a proxy, but there was none. In the end, when trying to boot into safe mode, I accidentally broke something in the Windows partition, so Windows offered me to restore from a previous recovery point. I did so... and things worked. Thanks to everybody for your efforts.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you must be using Chrome or Firefox, which can install some malware softwares/addons to them which may eventually hinder the connections.

Try using Internet Explorer for checking the Internet Connection. Also, if this has problems then Goto `Internet Options` in the `settings` in `IE`. Then, goto `Connections` tab, check the `LAN Settings`. These settings must be set properly(mostly they are automatic).

Also, check what last program did you install. Mostly network programs like `connectify`, or port occupying program like `Skype` cause these troubles.

If you have done all the above, then its a well that everything is appropriately setup. I have found that this problem occurs due to the DNS servers you are using. Today, I myself encountered this trouble in my PC but now its working fine.

As most of us would be using some sort of modem/routers for the internet connection, this makes us necessary to check all the devices that bring us the internet. So, I logged into the `Modem Administrative Area`, and did some changes.

1. Change `DNS Relay` to `User Discovered DNS only`
2. Change DNS to `8.8.8.8` and secondary to `8.8.4.4` (`Google DNS` fast, you may use any you like)
3. Save settings.

Your internet works.

Take a look at images below for clarification.

Interface Area, LAN settings (I use LAN, others might use WIFI, change appropriate settings:

[image]

User relay:

[image]

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Yes, you are right. I don't have reputation to comment.

Comment: You can read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: I tried using the 3 different browsers that are installed in the computer: Chrome, IE and Opera. None of them would connect.

Comment: The best you can do at this time is to restore your PC to a previous state where your internet was fine. And please don't install bogus material on your computer. Also,  maintain the installed programs section to check any untrustworthy software program installed.

Comment: Try changing to Comodo DNS or Google DNS.